# Error Im getting is - Null Function(DataSnapshot) can;t be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(DatabaseEvent)'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Error Im getting is - Null Function(DataSnapshot) can;t be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr Function(DatabaseEvent)'Im trying to retrieve data from firebase but it is not happening.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    
      final textcontroller = TextEditingController();
      final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
      final Future<FirebaseApp> _future = Firebase.initializeApp();
      //FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    
    
    
    
      void addData(String data) {
        databaseRef.child("Valve").set({Flow : 'ON'});
      }
      void addData2(String data) {
        databaseRef.child("Valve").set({Flow : 'OFF'});
      }
    
    
    
      void ReadData_once() {
        databaseRef.child("FirebaseIOT").child("LatestReading").once().then((DataSnapshot Snapshot) {
          print();
    
        });//this is the error
      }
    
      void printFirebase(){
        databaseRef.once().then((DataSnapshotsnapshot) {
    
          print('Data : ');
        });
      }//this is where error is coming
```

Comment: Yes you can edit your question. Please delete this question or that you wrote 2 hours a go.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of DataSnapshot, you should put DatabaseEvent within the `then`

So this part

`databaseRef.child("FirebaseIOT").child("LatestReading").once().then((DataSnapshot Snapshot) {print('test')}`

should be

`databaseRef.child("FirebaseIOT").child("LatestReading").once().then((DatabaseEvent event) {print('test')}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not a dart/flutter programmer but i know that you have to initialize app before any other modules you want to use from firebase library.

**So try to switch this lines:**

```js
final Future<FirebaseApp> _future = Firebase.initializeApp();
final databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
```

And i'm pretty sure `initializeApp()` needs firebase config object so you should initialize like this: `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`.

I don't know what is this: `Future<FirebaseApp>` why you force to get initialization result to be this future generic object ?